# Jquery select last on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the last ID of a bootstrap "well" in jquery.

This works but not on the ajax loaded wells, see my attempt below, any advice?

```
var newest = $('.well:last').attr('id');
setInterval(function() {
console.log(newest);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/getNew.php',
    data: "id="+newest+"&session=<?php echo $sesh; ?>",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $("#convo").append(html);
        newest = $(html).filter('.well:last').attr('id');
    }
    });
}, 3000);
```

The var newest is undefined after a new well is added by a successful ajax result.

Comment: Depends on the value of `html`. Maybe you need `.find` instead of `.filter`. But instead of parsing the HTML twice, you could just do `$("#convo").find('.well').last().attr('id')`.

Comment: Assuming `#convo` is a div on the page, and assuming `html` contains a new `.well` element, I think should try calling `$('.well:last').attr('id');`from within the success handler too, why do you use filter?

Comment: Is `$(html)` a valid call here..? or should  use `$("#convo").find('.well:last')` better... Anybody..?

Comment: `newest = $('.well:last').attr('id');` inside the success handler is undefined

Comment: '$("#convo").find('.well:last')' is returning `[div#27.well well-small, prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: document, selector: "#convo .well:last", constructor: function, init: function…]` and not the id

Comment: @VinceLowe .. Try: `$("#convo").find('.well:last').prop('id');`

Comment: Working with `$("#convo").find('.well').last().attr('id')`. please make answer so i can accept

Comment: @VinceLowe, Posted as answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
newest = $("#convo").find('.well:last').prop('id');
```

Or:

```
newest = $("#convo").find('.well').last().prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no root element. Thats why it doesnt work.
You can try following code and selector:

```
rootedHtml = "<div>"+html+"</div>";
newest = $(rootedHtml).find('.well[id]:last');
var id = newest.attr(id);
```

Please also check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qyEJu/